# how to test http request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, jasmine, karma-runner

i am new to angularjs ,i have done with my first angular app now i want to test them as well in my app i get some Json data from url and populate in a list i want to test http request but my test fails 
here is my controllerspec:

```
describe('myAppCtrl', function() {
    var scope, controller, httpBackend;


    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it('should populate the reddit data when the HTTP request succeeds', function() {

        httpBackend.when('GET','https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json').respond({names});

        controller('myAppCtrl', {'$scope': scope });
        httpBackend.flush();
        scope.$apply();

        expect(scope.names.children.length).toEqual(25);

    });
    it('should show the number of items in list',function() {
        var data = $('#title');
        expect(data).toBeTruthy();
        //expect(1).toBe(1);
    }); 


});
```

[Here is my app in plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/4jttdczt/)

Answer (score 1):

To make it fully testable you need some fixes in your controller which are as follows.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller("myAppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.names = []
     //watch sortBy
     $scope.$watch(function () {
         return $scope.sortExpression
     }, function (newSort) {
         $scope.sortBy = 'data.' + $scope.sortExpression
     })

     $scope.init = function(){
        return  $http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json")
         .success(function (response) {
                 $scope.names = response.data.children;
                 return response;
          })
       }  
      $scope.init();  
 });

**testSpec.js**


    describe('myAppCtrl', function() {
        var scope, controller, httpBackend;
        var data = {
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "",
        "children": [{
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "domain": "theguardian.com",
                "banned_by": null,
                "media_embed": {},
                "subreddit": "worldnews",
                "selftext_html": null,
                "selftext": "",
                "likes": null,
                "suggested_sort": null,
                "user_reports": [],
                "secure_media": null,
                "link_flair_text": null,
                "id": "3ef7lv",
                "from_kind": null,
                "gilded": 0,
                "archived": false,
                "clicked": false,
                "report_reasons": null,
                "author": "anutensil",
                "media": null,
                "score": 4,
                "approved_by": null,
                "over_18": false,
                "hidden": false,
                "num_comments": 0,
                "thumbnail": "",
                "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh13",
                "edited": false,
                "link_flair_css_class": null,
                "author_flair_css_class": null,
                "downs": 0,
                "secure_media_embed": {},
                "saved": false,
                "removal_reason": null,
                "stickied": false,
                "from": null,
                "is_self": false,
                "from_id": null,
                "permalink": "/r/worldnews/comments/3ef7lv/beekilling_pesticides_quietly_permitted_by_the_uk/",
                "name": "t3_3ef7lv",
                "created": 1437752870.0,
                "url": "http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/jul/23/bee-killing-pesticides-quietly-permitted-by-the-uk-government",
                "author_flair_text": null,
                "title": "Bee-killing pesticides quietly permitted by the UK govt",
                "created_utc": 1437724070.0,
                "distinguished": null,
                "mod_reports": [],
                "visited": false,
                "num_reports": null,
                "ups": 4
            }
        }, {
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "domain": "m.sputniknews.com",
                "banned_by": null,
                "media_embed": {},
                "subreddit": "worldnews",
                "selftext_html": null,
                "selftext": "",
                "likes": null,
                "suggested_sort": null,
                "user_reports": [],
                "secure_media": null,
                "link_flair_text": "Ukraine/Russia",
                "id": "3ef6q4",
                "from_kind": null,
                "gilded": 0,
                "archived": false,
                "clicked": false,
                "report_reasons": null,
                "author": "dexter93",
                "media": null,
                "score": 0,
                "approved_by": null,
                "over_18": false,
                "hidden": false,
                "num_comments": 2,
                "thumbnail": "",
                "subreddit_id": "t5_2qh13",
                "edited": false,
                "link_flair_css_class": "ukrassia",
                "author_flair_css_class": null,
                "downs": 0,
                "secure_media_embed": {},
                "saved": false,
                "removal_reason": null,
                "stickied": false,
                "from": null,
                "is_self": false,
                "from_id": null,
                "permalink": "/r/worldnews/comments/3ef6q4/french_lawmakers_surprised_by_happy_citizens_in/",
                "name": "t3_3ef6q4",
                "created": 1437752114.0,
                "url": "http://m.sputniknews.com/russia/20150724/1024986748.html",
                "author_flair_text": null,
                "title": "French Lawmakers Surprised by \u2018Happy\u2019 Citizens in Crimea\u2019s Yalta / Sputnik International",
                "created_utc": 1437723314.0,
                "distinguished": null,
                "mod_reports": [],
                "visited": false,
                "num_reports": null,
                "ups": 0
            }

        }],
        "after": "t3_3eeqtg",
        "before": null
    }
}



    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        controller = $controller;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it('should populate the reddit data when the HTTP request succeeds', function(done) {

        httpBackend.when('GET','https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json').respond({data:data});

        controller('myAppCtrl', {'$scope': scope });
        httpBackend.flush();
        scope.$apply();

        scope.init().then(function(resp){
            expect(resp.data).not.toBeNull();
               done();
        });

    });
    it('should show the number of items in list',function() {
        var data = $('#title');
        expect(data).toBeTruthy();
        //expect(1).toBe(1);
    }); 


    });
```

[check out plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yqKme59WD9isrZTCutKB?p=preview)

Comment: i want to test that the total item coming from Json which is 25 but i run your test as you suggest that's also not working it says names is not defined what can i do now?

Comment: its because you were passing {names } in respond .now see edited one

Comment: still receiving error it says can not read property  'children' of undefined at myAppCtrl.js at line 8

Comment: check out no error in code ,.. http://plnkr.co/edit/pln3dO7xDqmyO1Uzgf23?p=preview

Comment: yes you are right but same code i have and by running test it fails and same error as i mentioned above application is running fine but my expect is not pass it failed

Comment: got it  y it is showing error just follow the changed

Comment: its still not working and you hard code the data variable with jason file i need just from url data note hard code can you demonstrate

Comment: can i do this without hard coded form if yes please guide me

Comment: u just create a plunkr then i can help better way

Comment: your plunker is not for jasmine test

Comment: what should i do for that i am first time working on it can you elaborate it?

Comment: Battle of the plunkers

Comment: Your test should not use the live URL to get data, it should use mocked up data as shown in the answer. You are testing your code, not the the Reddit end point. Your test should not be dependent on the end-point - if it fails your test will fail. Which is incorrect behaviour. Your test should only fail if your code is faulty.

Comment: agree with @SimonHolmes